# NestJS + Graphql generate type file into the source shcme folder, not src directionary

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I use NestJS with Graphql, and want to genrate type file with the schema.

generate type code

```
import { GraphQLDefinitionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';

const definitionsFactory = new GraphQLDefinitionsFactory();
definitionsFactory.generate({
  typePaths: ['./src/**/*.graphql'],
  path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/**/*.ts'),
  outputAs: 'class',
  watch: true,
  emitTypenameField: true,
});
```

above code generate graphql.ts, but i want to generate users.ts in users folder
[image]

here is what i want to generate type file dirctionary
[image]